# Hii there, can we get data from store using useSelector() but ouside the functional component react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, useselector

can i get data from store redux by using useSelector() but outside the functional component react js?

i try using useSelector() as a ordinary function but return error because useSelector() running ouside the functional react component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Import your store, then call `getState()` to access the current state. For example:

```js
import store from './mystore.js';
// ...
const someData = store.getState().data;
```

Comment: is there another way bro?

Comment: @DanangIpulBasrin Is there some reason you can't use getState?

Comment: I can use this method in another project, but in my project right now, my company doesnt allow exporting the store.

Comment: Then you can export a function in store.js which can return specific state that you want.